# Display Reactive form data on same page after click on Save button in Angular10

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, angular10, angular14

I have a reactive form and once user click on Save button it should show the save data on the same page in a block and once user click on Submit it should call the api.

How can I show the reactive form data on same page after user click on Save button.
The page is not getting refreshed so I don't know how to show it after clicking on Save button.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and what's not working?

Answer (score 1):

Your reactive form instance already has all of the data you need to display it's value in the template via `.value`:

```html
  <div>
    {{ form.value }}
  </div>
```

No need for using the `json` pipe, assigning extra properties, etc. As your form's value changes, it will be reflected in the template.

Subsequently, you can use the same data to pass to your service call. If your reactive form contains disabled fields, and you need those values as well, you can use `.getRawValue()`

If you *really* only want the data to show when you click the save button, I would wrap the display of the form data with a boolean property that's set when you click "save", or perhaps when the form is `.valid`

Answer (score 0):

Once you click Save button, call a method where you will store your form values to one variable(savedData), and you can show that in template.

For example:

HTML:

```
<button (click)='save()'>Save</button>

<p *ngIf='savedData'> {{ savedData | json }} </p>
```

TS:

```
savedData = null;

save() {
   this.savedData = this.form.values
}
```